# PHP make iteration through big array in steps

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I load data from a huge XML-File into an array. That's fine for now, is the memory of the web server not overloaded. But as soon as I try to iterate through that array to work with the data, then I get a memory error. Setting memory-limit to -1 is not an option, obviously.

So, what I am trying to do, is iterating through the array step by step. Like the first 1,000 entries and then the next till there are no more entries left. Like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($entries as $entry) {
    // Do some stuff with the entries
    if (++$i == 1000) break;
}
```

I now want to iterate through the next 1.000 entries. My idea was to address the key of the array. Like doing the loop again but from entries[1000]. But I can't get the break from the loop and going back into the loop again going.

Is, what I try to achieve, even possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Would [array_​chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) help?

Comment: *"I load data from a huge XML-File into an array."*: Don't do that, use XMLReader to extract what you need, eventually store needed data in a dbms.

Comment: @brombeer thats actually something i will have a look at, thank you!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I get this XML from another web server and need every entry there is. I should have clarified before, that I have multiple XML Files and merge them together in an array I can then iterate through and save all of this in a WordPress Database

Comment: Be careful in PHP arrays are passed as copies and not references. This can chew up memory quite quickly as well.

Comment: PHP isn't designed to deal with a huge amount of data (in particular if you project to load them in memory at the same time). Forget your big array, change your approach! For a DBMS a huge amount of data isn't a problem at all, use it! Give short excerpts of your xml files (with dummy data eventually, but with clear data) and show what you want to do with them and how looks the tables in which you want to store the result. But please, stop to dream with your giant array!

Answer (score -1):

from what you did
I think you should have done this instead

```
for ($i=0; $i>=1000; $i++){

}
```

Note: the `$i=0` is when you want it to start counting from zero but if you want it to count from 1 then replace the 0 with 1

Comment: The question is not about how to iterate over an array

Answer (score -1):

Try this if your data is really Big and slow your web server:

```
for($i = 1;$i <= count($entries);$i++) {       
   if($i % 1000 === 0) {
     // your code here        
   }
     usleep(100000); // delays execution for 0.1 second x 1000 entries
 }
```

Comment: When i implement it like this, i still get memory exceed

Comment: Increase value inside sleep() maybe

Comment: That code would run anything! The `if` clause never gets triggered, it would just `sleep(5)` for every iteration

Comment: He will replace `// your code here` and  `do some stuff with the entries` as he said by calling some functions like array_push() and others...

Comment: How would adding sleep solve a memory issue?